# XCOM automated armor coloring by class

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I'm playing XCOM Enemy Unknown (including Enemy Within) for a while now, and I was wondering if there was a way to automate the coloring of the armor (as well as automating the armor skin and helmet).
I have to do this manually each time, which makes this a pain..

For example:

- Assault class - Red
- Support - Pink
- Heavy - Black
- Sniper - Green
- (MEC (+ class, if possible) - Yellow

Is there any way to color the armor (as well as the armor skin and the helmet) of the different classes automatically?

And if possible: Is this also possible for MEC, MELD and PSI soldiers? (with their corresponding class, may be too much to ask)

**Note: preferred standalone mod / tweak (The LongWar mod forces you to use the gamemode mod as well, I'll look into if only the armor coloring can be run)**

Comment: In the base game there wasn't. I doubt Enemy Within changed that (haven't tried it yet). But I do not know about the mod scene. There may be a solution there.

Comment: It's definitely possible but I can't find a mod for the vanilla game that does this. It's included in the Long War mod but that's also involve playing Long War.

Comment: @Studoku Thanks for the info, Would be worth the effort to investigate, will let you know if I find something.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like the LongWar mod has this option available. There's a thread on Reddit about this functionality - below is a quote, but essentially it appears to be a built-in function of the mod, and you can customise by editing **DefaultGameCore.ini**.

> LongWar is configured to change the color of your troops armor and headgear when they are first promoted into a class specialty. This is a great feature that can allow you at a glance to see where your sniper or medic is on the battlefield.

http://www.reddit.com/r/Xcom/comments/2b5hgf/lw_setting_the_color_code_for_your_soldier_classes/

Comment: This is correct. But as @Studoku mentioned: This is only in conjunction with the LongWar mod. I'll update the question to specify the standalone tweak / mod. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Darn, didn't see that - apologies. If nothing else, though, the content of that reddit thread indicates that it's *possible* to set up with mods and/or ini customisation - so hopefully someone else will have / be able to suggest a standalone method.